# Django view doesn't render correctly after location.reload()

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-views, jquery-countdown

I have a `DetailView` where I render details about object of my `models.Auction` , including expires parameter (using `jquery.countdown` to countdown time & fire event after finished).

Here is the code for the countdown & finish event:

```
<script>
$('#clock').countdown('{{ auction.get_time_left }}', function(event) {
      $(this).html(event.strftime('%D {% trans "day/days" %} %H:%M:%S'));
    }).on('finish.countdown', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ location.reload()}, 1500);
 });
</script>
```

On the view  i check if:
`if datetime.now() >= context['auction'].expires:`, and I render a different template;

But for some reasons when it does the `location.reload()` it doesn't check that condition(skips it) and renders the same template (with time expired).
P.S. I've also tried priniting something in the terminal ( but it skips the printing as well )

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `reload()` method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true:

```
location.reload(true).
```

Comment: Good to know , thanks. I've already fixed it , I forgot to pass the seconds to the jquery countdown (only days,hours,mins), so that's why the calculation in the view didn't match with the countdown ending.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to pass the seconds to the jquery countdown (only days,hours,mins), so that's why the calculation in the view didn't match with the countdown ending.